# How to remove a Program from Microsoft Partner Center

Tags: authentication, center, xbox

I am triyng to activate the dev mode in my Xbox One X. I paid to enter in Microsoft Partner Center to enable the dev mode in my Xbox. I opened the app in my xbox to connect to the Partner Center but it's not connecting. I guess I know why. I use an email *****@outlook.com in my Xbox. I had an very old email like this: ****@msn.com. This one was used like alias during a long time. When I subscribed to the Partner Center I don't know why but this old email was used to register the Windows & Xbox Agreement in the Partner Center. I use to login in my Xbox my new email: ****@outlook.com. And I log in the Partner Center with the same email. But in the agreement is registered the old email. I guess it's because of that I can't connect my Xbox to Partner Center. Is there any way to change the email of the Agreement or delete the Windows & Xbox Program and assign again with the new email?